# Repeated function over varnames

Tags: r, list, character, lapply

Using the following dataframe (similar to my data, but much smaller):

```
id <- c(1:10)
clo_a <- c(rep(c("Yes","No"), 5))
clo_f <- c(rep(c(4,5), 5))
man_a <- c(rep(c("Yes","No"), each = 5))
man_f <- c(rep(c(c(3,7)), each = 5))
pho_a <- c(rep(c(NA, NA, "Yes", NA, "No"), 2))
pho_f <- c(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 2))

ds <- data.frame(id, clo_a, clo_f, man_a, man_f, pho_a, pho_f)
```

produces a dataframe ds as follows:

```
   id clo_a clo_f man_a man_f pho_a pho_f
1   1   Yes     4   Yes     3  <NA>     1
2   2    No     5   Yes     3  <NA>     2
3   3   Yes     4   Yes     3   Yes     3
4   4    No     5   Yes     3  <NA>     4
5   5   Yes     4   Yes     3    No     5
6   6    No     5    No     7  <NA>     1
7   7   Yes     4    No     7  <NA>     2
8   8    No     5    No     7   Yes     3
9   9   Yes     4    No     7  <NA>     4
10 10    No     5    No     7    No     5
```

I now want to select the id's of the variables ending in _a with "Yes", but also the values of the variables ending in _f, albeit ideally separately.

As one example I can write:

```
upset_clo_a <- ds$id[which( ds$clo_a == "Yes")]
```

producing:

```
> upset_clo_a
[1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

I'd now like the repeat this for all variables, ideally using a vector with the common denominator in the set of variables, susch as:

```
ai_list <- c("clo", "man", "pro")
```

Obviously the following example doesn't work. I tried several variants of using `paste()` or `substitute()`, not yielding anything useful.

```
lapply(ai_list, function(x) {
  upset_x <- ds$id[which( ds$x == "Yes")]
})
```

The output is the same for all variants I tried:

```
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
integer(0)
```

In the end I want to (for example) read the ID-vectors per variable (e.g. upset_clo_f) as list of vectors into an upSet plot.
Maybe you have a great idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste the missing part (`_a`) in each vector element and use it to subset your data.frame. Then loop over those columns and get the index of `Yes`, i.e.

```
sapply(ds[names(ds) %in% paste0(ai_list, '_a')], function(i)which(i == 'Yes'))
```

**Breaking down the code**

- `paste0(ai_list, '_a')` - Pastes the suffix *[_a]* to each name (clo_a, man_a, pro_a)
- `names(ds) %in% paste0(ai_list, '_a')` - Returns a logical vector (TRUE, FALSE) which will be used for sub setting the columns of interest
- `ds[names(ds) %in% paste0(ai_list, '_a')]` - Returns a data frame with only the columns of interest (as per logical conditions from above step)
- `sapply(ds[names(ds) %in% paste0(ai_list, '_a')], function(i)which(i == 'Yes'))` - Finally, we loop over the columns and apply the `which()` function to get the indices of `YES`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything in that code, but it works =) Thanks!

Comment: @PhilippStaudacher I added some more explanation. I hope it's clear now. Please ask me If you have any further questions

Comment: Thanks a lot. Essentially it's all very logic, except haven't used sapply (or lapply) much to date. I'll see how I can adapt this for my next problems. Very well explained!